# Clarifications regarding the extra filterable attributes for product import in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to know the function of this column in magento2x product import csv template.

**additional_attributes** column

1) How to map extra attributes (filterables in particular) to products?

2) Where can we check once added?

3) How to configure the same?

4) Also, how to add 'Brand' attribute in Magento2?

Answer (score 0):

Add all your additional attributes in the attribute code - additional_attributes

Ex : climate=All-Weather|Cold|Cool|Mild|Windy|Wintry,eco_collection=Yes,erin_recommends=No,pattern=Solid

climate - Multi select attribute
eco_collection - Yes / No (or) Drop Down attribute
pattern - Input attribute

Comment: can you suggest me how to give the attributes here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137242/how-to-map-custom-attributes-to-specific-attribute-sets-magento2

Comment: How to give the type in csv for :  if it is multiselect, drop down ...which column?

Comment: No need to mention , just add attribute code & its value in mentioned format.

Comment: Just like we had a plugin in Magento1x for bulk attribute import, thr is no plugin in Magento2, cause what if we have 20-25 attributes for a product, do we have to give comma seperated for all in a single column(additional_attributes) ?

Comment: Yes , you can add 'n' number of custom attributes separated by commas. It is working fine.