# Format for adding custom attributes in additional_attributes column

Tags: magento2

I have few attributes which have to be mapped to specific attribute set.
How to achieve the same in Magento 2x csv template.

Eg:

My attribute set : **Desktop**

Has 4 products .

**Attributes are:**

Brand

Series

Model No.

Type

Colour

Read/Write Speed

Lock Port

Built-in Webcam

Sensor Resolution

How should i give this in my csv along with **attribute values** ??

I m following the magento2 csv product template format.

Comment: do you mean while import product how to assign to particular attribute set? if yes, you have the column in csv "attribute_set_code" here you map your product to "Desktop" attriubute set

Comment: That i got, i have mapped Desktop set to all my 4 products, i need to map my custom attributes (brand, series, modelno along with some values) to each product of 'Desktop', i know it has to be done thru col 'additional_attributes'...Doubt is how to give the values for different types like for drop down, select etc

Comment: cant we not achieve | seperated vales in 'additional_attributes' col like color=Black|Red|Blue ??

Comment: that is simple! assign value to custom attribute. assign value in "additional_attribute" column. If you need detail answer, I will update. please change your title, it is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Ok please give a detailed answer with eg explained